# How read multiple csv file from zip and import in different dataframe in R?

Tags: r, import, zip

I have 4 files csv in zip file `Patrimonio.zip`

```
a.csv
b.csv
c.csv
z.csv
```

I want read these files from zip and import in R in 4 differents dataframe. In the file csv the sep is "|".

There is a method for create 4 different dataframe with a loop on without a loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do :

```
unzip('Path/to/Patrimonio.zip')
file_names <- list.files(pattern = "\\.csv$", full.names = TRUE)
list_files <- lapply(file_names, read.csv, sep = "|")
```

This will give you list of dataframes in `list_files`, you can keep them in a list or if you want separate data frames, we can name the list and use `list2env` to get all dataframe separately.

```
names(list_files) <- sub("\\.csv", "", basename(file_names))
list2env(list_files, .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: Hi, How can I modified the code above for read cvs from zip without extract file .csv?

Comment: @Andrea Do you mean you want to read all the files and not only the ones which end with "csv"? If yes, you can remove the `pattern` argument and replace the 2nd line with `file_names <- list.files(full.names = TRUE)`

Comment: I want read the files csv in zip without extract these. And create dataframe with the new name no with the file name